# httpUrlConnection object passing between activities android

Tags: android, object, parameter-passing, scribe

I am using scribe Oauth1.0 in Android Studio. I have successfully connected. But I need to pass the HttpUrlConnection object called "request" to other activities to access various API.How to pass the request object ?

Comment: The request is something you send so you should have it.
Could you please elaborate why you need this?

Comment: not clear, please explain more